# New Databricks JDBC driver version doesn't recognize JDBC URL

Tags: jdbc, databricks, databricks-sql

I had been using the Databricks JDBC driver version 2.6.22 and tried to upgrade to 2.6.27. However, after upgrading I get messages saying my JDBC URLs are invalid when trying to connect. These JDBC URLs work fine with the old version of the driver and I pull them directly from the Databricks SQL endpoint info, so I expect something else is going on.

Example JDBC URL:
`jdbc:spark://[workspace domain]:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;AuthMech=3;httpPath=/sql/1.0/endpoints/[identifier]`

I noticed between versions the name went from `SimbaSparkJDBC42-2.6.22.1040` to `DatabricksJDBC42-2.6.27.1048` and the JAR class name went from `com.simba.spark.jdbc.Driver` to `com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver`. Does dropping Simba mean there was a more major change? Do I need to correct my JDBC URLs somehow?

I'm downloading my driver from [here](https://databricks.com/spark/jdbc-drivers-download)

I'm using DBeaver as my SQL client if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDBC URLs for the new databricks driver start with `jdbc:databricks:` instead of `jdbc:spark:`. As of now, JDBC URL details in the UI still use the old format, just replace `spark` with `databricks` and they should work. Mentioned [here](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/dbeaver.html#language-SQL%C2%A0warehouse)

Answer (score 0):

Databricks has a different URL format, check the documentation [here](https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi.html#databricks-jdbc)

Basically in the url replace spark to databricks and add PWD parameter.

```
jdbc:databricks://[workspace domain]:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;AuthMech=3;httpPath=/sql/1.0/endpoints/[identifier];PWD=[your_access_token]
```

PWD is the personal access token. [Instructions to get access token](https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi.html#authentication).